# GROUP, SUM and DATE DIFFERENCE Entity Framework with LINQ

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

I want to sum all the spent amount by each customer and then divide the result by the date of the first registration of the customer in the database; the result of the division will determine the most profitable and the least profitable customer.

The Customer table looks like:

```
 public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
    public int DayOB{ get; set; }
    public int MonthOB{ get; set; }
    public int YearOB{ get; set; }
    public string Genre{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Cellular{ get; set; }
    public bool Privacy { get; set; }
    public bool Profilation{ get; set; }
    public bool Marketing { get; set; }
    public decimal Points{ get; set; }
    public decimal ConversionRate{ get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDate{ get; set; }
    public string QRCode { get; set; }
}
```

While the Transaction table like:

```
 public class Transaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal SpentAmount{ get; set; }
    public decimal AddedCoupon{ get; set; }
    public decimal DeductCoupon{ get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate{ get; set; }

    //FOREIGN KEY
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    //NAVIGATION
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

For the moment I've tried this LINQ query

```
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTransactions()
    {
        /*DateTime regDate= from c in db.Customers
                           select c.RegisterDate.Date;*/

        DateTime currentDay= DateTime.UtcNow;

        var query = from c in db.Customers
                    join t in db.Transactions on c.Id equals t.CustomerId
                    where t.Id != null
                    group t by t.CustomerId into ris
                    select new
                    {
                        CustomerId = ris.Key,
                        RegisterDate= ris.Select(c => c.Customer.RegisterDate.Date.Subtract(currentDay)),
                        Sum = ris.Sum(t => t.SpentAmount)
                    };

        return Ok(query.OrderByDescending(ris => ris.Sum));
    }
```

The result look like:

```
[
    {
        "CustomerId": 6,
        "RegisterDate": [
            "2020-03-01T00:00:00",
            "2020-03-01T00:00:00"
        ],
        "Sum": 46.00
    },
    {
        "CustomerId": 7,
        "RegisterDate": [
            "2019-11-01T00:00:00",
            "2019-11-01T00:00:00"
        ],
        "Sum": 45.50
    },
    {
        "CustomerId": 5,
        "RegisterDate": [
            "2020-02-01T00:00:00",
            "2020-02-01T00:00:00"
        ],
        "Sum": 31.00
    }
]
```

The part of grouping for `CustomerId` and the Sum are the right results, but when I try the part of making the difference between the current day and the registration day, then divide it with the amount spent it gives me errors.

Comment: Your output doesn't match your shown code.

Comment: @NetMage What do you mean ? I've tried it again and the result is this.. The only thing I changed was RegisterDay to RegisterDate in the Select statement

Comment: *it gives me errors* -- Which?

Comment: @GertArnold It say that LINQ doesn't accept DateTime and any of it's methods. For sure that part isn't good, but I've tired to see what happen.

Comment: The `select` posted in your question has neither `RegisterDay` or `RegisterDate` but rather `PassedDay`. Did you post the wrong code?

Comment: @NetMage Oh yes, you're right; it was a previous test in wich I was trying to get the RegitserDate an then subtract it from the CurrentDay.

Comment: "The result look like" - if you get an error you can't have a result - is that how you want the result to look? How can the difference between two date/times be a date?

Comment: @NetMage It's the result without the part of subtract between the two dates; though the register date should be a single result, but I think it's a List because of the groupby. The result of the subtraction should be an INT, but like a said before LINQ does not accept the subtract method

Comment: What would the int's value represent?

Comment: @NetMage It would rapresent the passed day between the two dates. I've read somewhere that the result of the subtraction of two dates should be an int, is it wrong ?

Comment: In C# the result of a subtraction of two `DateTime` structs is a `TimeSpan` struct. If you want the result in days, you would need to use the `TimeSpan.TotalDays` method for fractional days and `TimeSpan.Days` for integer days in the timespan.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you cant use c# classes and methods(`Customer.RegisterDate.Date.Subtract`) in ef. So you have 2 variants:

1) Do your calculations after query.ToList() in web part of your application. I guess it will work:

```
var query = from c in db.Customers
                    join t in db.Transactions on c.Id equals t.CustomerId
                    where t.Id != null
                    group t by t.CustomerId into ris;
                    select new
                    {
                        CustomerId = ris.Key,
                        RegisterDate = ris.Select(c => c.Customer.RegisterDate)
                        Sum = ris.Sum(t => t.SpentAmount)
                    };
var result = query.ToList().Select(x => new {x.CustomerId, PassedDay = RegisterDate.Date.Subtract(currentDay), Sx.Sum });
return Ok(result.OrderByDescending(ris => ris.Sum));
```

2) Ef can do with datetime compare operations('>', '='...) and special dbfunctions(docs in url lower). U can rewrite code with it.

dbfunctions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working, I cannot access the ris in the "result" query :\

Comment: I wrote the code in a notebook for an example, it needs to be corrected for work.
This is how it will most likely work.                                                                             var result = query.ToList().Select(x => new {x.CustomerId, PassedDay = RegisterDate.Date.Subtract(currentDay), Sx.Sum }); I change answer code too.

Comment: Yeah I had correct it to try to make it work, but RegisterDate is an IEnumerable<DateTime> and it hasn't a .Date method.

Comment: Infact I don't want the RegisterDate to be in a list, but I want the sigle date. For the moment I got stuck on these two things :\. PS: thank you for supporting me !